# When opening Word from Excel, Cannot find path specified

Tags: vba

I'm opening word from excel in my macro using the following code:

```
Dim wdApp As Word.Application

Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
```

It works on all of the computers in our office, except for one.  I'm getting the error:
Run-time error
The system cannot find the path specified

Does anyone have any ideas?  I have uninstalled all forms of office from the computer and reinstalled it.  I've verified that word is in the correct location, or at least the same location it is on all other computers in the office, and I've successfully run word using shell() on the problematic computer.

Comment: Side note (unlikely to fix the issue): You're mixing early- and late-binding. Best to be consistent: `Dim wdApp as Word.Application`, `Set wdApp = New Word.Application`. Or, `Dim wdApp As Object`, `Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was something wrong with the profile I was using. It was showing 2 options for Word, along with all of the office apps.  I was unable to get rid of the 2nd option, so I ended up recreating the profile, and now it works.